# On the command line, npx playwright test -g "test name" gives "no tests found", but Test Explorer sees it

Tags: command-line, playwright, playwright-test

In VSCode, the Test Explorer can see tests. I can Run Test, Debug Test, and Go To Test. But when I try to run the same test from the command line, it says "no tests found."

```
% npx playwright test -g "do something neato"
Running 0 tests using 0 workers
=================
 no tests found.
=================
```

[image: 1]

Comment: There are other tests in my project that work as expected from the command line. All file names end in '.spec.js' and are in the same directory. The VSCode extension Playwright Test For VSCode is installed, and it adds it's run/debug annotation to the left of the all the tests, as expected. Only the command line fails.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes updating the test list ist necessary when you edited the test Script!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).